# Hosting .NET Control In ASP.NET App

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a COM control that wraps a lot of client side functionality, i.e. using input devices to gather information, integration with different devices, report formation, etc... I would like to wrap this inside a .NET control of some sort and add it to an ASP.NET application. The wrapper will be responsible for speaking with our database located on a server and also contain a little business logic. Does anyone have a good general or even better a specific direction I should be heading in? I am using C# in .NET and the COM object is in C++.

BTW, I have tried to create a windows forms control Library and hosting it in a ASP web app but I have had no success with that.

Comment: That won't work.  You need to rewrite it from scratch in HTML and Javascript.

Comment: BTW, I am using .NET 4.0

Comment: Rewriting the control is not an option.

Comment: Using the control in ASP.Net is not an option either.  Sorry.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/09/19/hosting-a-windows-form-control-in-a-web-page.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You might host an ActiveX inside a webpage. ActiveX is COM - but there are limitations what an Active control can do when hosted inside a browser. Browsers are commonly developed with sandboxing in mind, so you might run into *serious* problems in regard to security settings. Another aspect is cross browser capabilities. WinForms is definitely another world, so even if you find a way to display some sort of a simple form, you're most surely ending up somewhere between mess and boom.

From what you told in your question, I think your best option is to stick with a classic desktop application. Apparently, this does work for you, and changing the way the application behaves isn't an option besides the fact, that a rewrite is too costly. Migrating a rather complex app to the web, with it's radical different programming approach compared to classic desktop applications, won't go along with limited amount of resources (money and/or human).

That said, **if** you're going to take the burden of mess and boom, you might want to look at that information:

http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2007/06/18/including-a-winforms-user-control-in-an-asp-net-web-page/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4953/Simple-way-to-expose-a-NET-WinForm-control-as-an-A

Note, the articles are rather old and don't solve the problem, that the ActiveX / COM stuff used by the form has to be registered on the client machine (as well as issues like accessing servers that may or may not be in the same network anymore). And you can't be sure about security settings.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be confusing the difference between System.Windows.Forms (WinForms) which run on the desktop within the Windows OS, and System.Web.UI (WebForms) which run under IIS within a very different security environment in ASP.NET. Just because many of the form properties and such have been made to look similar, it does not mean they work anything alike internally - and in fact, they most certainly do not. You need to take a closer look at how WebForms work within ASP.NET to begin to understand why, as SLaks pointed out for you already, that what you are attempting to do cannot work in the manner in which you are suggesting.